# Метод Обратного распространения ошибки в PyBrain

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, pybrain

Как в сверточной нейросети  реализовать  метод обратного распространения ошибки на питона.  Используется библиотека PyBrain.

Comment: http://pybrain.org/docs/quickstart/training.html

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 2):

[Пример](http://pybrain.org/docs/quickstart/training.html):

```
>>> from pybrain.supervised.trainers import BackpropTrainer

>>> net = buildNetwork(2, 3, 1, bias=True, hiddenclass=TanhLayer)
>>> trainer = BackpropTrainer(net, ds)

>>> trainer.train()
0.31516384514375834

>>> trainer.trainUntilConvergence()
...
```